# d3.js y-axis min and max value range display

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have data points from 5000 to 91200

```
y.domain(d3.extent(function(d) { return d.y; }));
```

It gives me the correct ouput `[5000, 91200]` but while displaying it changes to 10000.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "while displaying it's changed to 10000"?  Do you mean the tick mark labels?  When your domain is irregular, the labels will not always include the exact minimum and maximum of the domain.

Answer (score 4):

d3 uses the 'min' and 'max' functions to show only the lowest and highest numbers in your data

```
var max = d3.max(d3.values(data)); 
var min = d3.min(d3.values(data)); 
y.domain([min, max]);
```

The extent function actually does both of these functions automagically

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d; }));
```

If you show your code on jsfiddle I'll be able to narrow down your issue

Comment: I am facing same issue, how to solve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903947/how-to-set-y-axis-ydomain-value-to-max-in-d3-js