# How to set y axis (yDomain) value to max in D3 Js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In My D3 chart, How to set `yDomain` to the max value. Any suggestions ?
If we see on `nov 10` my `line` and `area` is going out of the box.

My Code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h)

[image]

I am calculating the two domains separately for yDomainMagnitude and yDomainStartupMagnitude, but now how to consolidate or take the union of both and assign to yDomain.

```
   var yDomainMagnitude = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.magnitude;
    });

    var yDomainStartupMagnitude = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.startupMagnitude;
    });

    var yDomain = yDomainStartupMagnitude; // here I have to have union of both and assign.

    var xScale = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(xDomain);
    var yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .domain(yDomain);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to calculate the `yDomain` in place. Yours does obviously work, it can be significantly simplified, though:

```
var yDomain = [
  d3.min(data, d => Math.min(d.magnitude, d.startupMagnitude)),
  d3.max(data, d => Math.max(d.magnitude, d.startupMagnitude))
];
```

This approach checks whatever value `magnitude` or `startupMagnitude` is smaller / greater using `Math.min()` / `Math.max()`, respectively, for any data point. It then utilizes `d3.min()` and `d3.max()` to calculate the global extent over those values.

Comment: `Math.min` and `d3.min` etc. behave differently, so it'd be worth using one or the other meaning without mixing it, unless all these are known to be true:
- all values are numbers
- there are no gaps in the data represented as `null`s
- the array is not empty

Answer (score 1):

As you have a relational condition inside your function, it'll always take the larger value. You could instead calculate the two domains separately for `startupMagnitude` and `magnitude`, and then union the extents (take the minimum and maximum of the minimum and maximum extent values, respectively).

```
const magnitude = d3.extent(data, d => d.magnitude);
const startup = d3.extent(data, d => d.startupMagnitude);
const yDomain = [
    d3.min([magnitude[0], startup[0]]),
    d3.max([magnitude[1], startup[1]])
];
```

Or, a single-assignment version, exploiting that you just union the extents:

```
const yDomain = d3.extent([
    ...d3.extent(data, d => d.magnitude), 
    ...d3.extent(data, d => d.startupMagnitude)
]);
```

Yet another is to union the data first, then compute the extent:

```
const yDomain = d3.extent([
    ...data.map(d => d.magnitude), 
    ...data.map(d => d.startupMagnitude)
]);
```

These don't mix the D3 way of calculating min/max/extent with the [different semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28596879/2242705) of `Math.min`/`Math.max`, eg. handling of strings, nulls, and results if the array is empty. In this regard, the last version is the most faithful to the D3 way, as it uses a single `d3.extent`.

Comment: I am having var max = d3.max(d3.values(data, function(d) {
      return d.magnitude;
    }));

    var min = d3.min(d3.values(data, function(d) {
      return d.startupMagnitude;
    }));  how to give this in yDomain, can you please guide

Comment: plus one for help, I am doing some calculations I posted answer please check

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am calculating the two domains separately for startupMagnitude and magnitude, and then comparing the max and min and creating the yDomain.

I am not sure this is correct or any other d3 method is there,

```
    var yDomainMagnitude = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.magnitude;
    });

    var yDomainStartupMagnitude = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.startupMagnitude;
    });

    var max =
        d3.max(d3.values(yDomainMagnitude)) >
        d3.max(d3.values(yDomainStartupMagnitude))
            ? d3.max(d3.values(yDomainMagnitude))
            : d3.max(d3.values(yDomainStartupMagnitude));
    var min =
        d3.min(d3.values(yDomainMagnitude)) <
        d3.min(d3.values(yDomainStartupMagnitude))
            ? d3.min(d3.values(yDomainMagnitude))
            : d3.min(d3.values(yDomainStartupMagnitude));
    var yDomain = [min, max];
```

Comment: Yes, but you can simplify a good bit, there's no benefit to conditionalizing the code - apparently code formatting doesn't work in this comment, so I pasted code examples into my original answer.